# Redirecting to different URL's after restoring the site on local

Tags: magento2.2.3, localhost, redirect-url

We have a development server to test our code changes before pushing them to live. Recently, we have restored the development server to local (xampp) for testing and also done the necessary changes to the **core_config_data** in database.

Though we have done the changes in **core_config_data**, most of the products still redirecting to the development server instead of showing them as a localhost URL. Hope you got my point.

I can understand that I have missed something but I don't know what it is.

Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**In core_config_data Table :-**

```
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 'your_site_url' WHERE config_id = '2';
UPDATE core_config_data SET value = 'your_site_url' WHERE config_id = '3';
```

**After core_config_data Changes Apply This Command :-**

```
sudo rm -rf pub/static/frontend/ pub/static/adminhtml/ pub/static/_requirejs pub/static/deployed_version.txt var/cache var/page_cache var/generation var/view_preprocessed var/session generated/code

sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade

sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f

sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex

sudo php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Run below command step by step.

> rm -rf var/* pub/static/* generated/*
>
> php bin/magento setup:upgrade
>
> php bin/magento setup:static:content:deploy -f
>
> php bin/magento cache:flush

After done all the command you check.